# How to pass an escape slash to subprocess.run

Tags: python, subprocess, escaping, string-literals

Trying to run command this from a Python script:

`gh api "/search/code?q=somecode" --jq ".items[] | { "file": .path, "repo": .repository[\"full_name\"] } "`

by way of:

`output = subprocess.run( [ 'gh',  f'api "/search/code?q={CODE}"',  '--jq ".items[] | {{ "file": .path, "repo": .repository[{}] }} "'.format('\\"full_name\\"') ])`

to no avail.

I've also tried:

`.format(r'\"full_name\"')`

which, afaik, is supposed to work, but I get

`Command '['gh', 'api "/search/code?q=somecode"', '--jq ".items[] | { "file": .path, "repo": .repository[\\"full_name\\"] } "']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Using `.format(repr('\"full_name\"'))` yields:

`Command '['gh', 'api "/search/code?q=staging-procore-tech-docs+org:procore"', '--jq ".items[] | { "file": .path, "repo": .repository[\'"full_name"\'] } "']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Thanks in advance! I've spent at least 3 hours reading docs, SO and asking friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have likewise attempted this on my Mac OS X (M1 chip) and ran into a similar issue on my end. I had originally installed the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) (`gh`) via homebrew (`brew`).

I have few points I would suggest fixing:

1. Use `shlex.split` to (unequivocally) split multi-word arguments into a list of arguments
2. Pass the full path to the command, which you can get by running `which gh` in a terminal
3. Use an `rf''` template- or f- string, where the `r` is for *raw string* so backslashes `\` are automatically escaped

Putting all this together:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import shlex
import subprocess

CODE = 'somecode'

# full path to `gh` command
GH_BINARY = '/opt/homebrew/bin/gh'

cmd: list[str] = shlex.split(rf'{GH_BINARY} api "/search/code?q={CODE}" --jq ".items[] | {{ "file": .path, "repo": .repository[\"full_name\"]}} "')
result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True)

print('Return Code:', result.returncode)
print('Output:', result.stdout.decode())
```

Output (redacted):

```
Return Code: 0
Output: {"file":"tuixiangzi-control/Debug/tuixiangzi-control.Build.CppClean.log","repo":"ChaoFeng-alone/tuixiangzi"}
{"file":"tuixiangzi-easyx/Debug/tuixiangzi-easyx.Build.CppClean.log","repo":"ChaoFeng-alone/tuixiangzi"}
...
```

Comment: Woooooww thank you! That's _exactly_ my setup. I love the M1, but man do rabbit holes go deep sometimes. Thank you so much! Sorry I can only upvote once :(

Comment: No problem! Glad it was helpful. And yeah, the M1 can sometimes be more trouble than it’s worth ;)